# Why I get XML Response since my header ask for Json

Tags: python

I started working with Python and Alexa RANK API, I have a little issue I try to get JSON response but I get XML response since I ask for JSON in my header as described on the web site https://awis.alexa.com/developer-guide

this is my code :

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': 'SMADth1A9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxEotx',
}

params = (
    ('Action', 'UrlInfo'),
    ('ResponseGroup', 'Rank'),
    ('Url', 'yahoo.com'),
)

response = requests.get('https://awis.api.alexa.com/api', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Awis>
  <OperationRequest>
    <RequestId>b14aa999-926d-47c5-87e6-f1fb0f53a40b</RequestId>
  </OperationRequest>
  <Results>
    <Result>
      <Alexa>
        <Request>
          <Arguments>
            <Argument>
              <Name>url</Name>
              <Value>yahoo.com</Value>
            </Argument>
            <Argument>
              <Name>responsegroup</Name>
              <Value>Rank</Value>
            </Argument>
          </Arguments>
        </Request>
        <TrafficData>
          <DataUrl>yahoo.com/</DataUrl>
          <Rank>12</Rank>
        </TrafficData>
      </Alexa>
    </Result>
    <ResponseStatus>
      <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
    </ResponseStatus>
  </Results>
</Awis>
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you share what the response looks like? You’re positive it’s XML? This seems like a rather glaring bug somewhere on Alexa’s end if it isn’t actually sending back the correct data format. If the response body is truly XML I would try to get in touch with them about it.

Comment: Why does your code is so different from the [official sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/alexa-web-information-service-api-samples/blob/master/python/awis.py)?

Comment: @esqew  please double check ;)

Comment: @esqew - there's no reason to expect a particular API to send back any particular format without specific knowledge that it can/should do so.  So unless their documentation says that the API supports sending back results in JSON format, the fact that it doesn't do so is not a bug.

Comment: @Steve The basis for my comment regarding this behavior being a bug is rooted in **the documentation OP linked above**, which clearly states the following, emphasis mine (alongside an example using cURL which sends along an `Accept` header value of `application/json`): "*A query request is simply an HTTP GET request that returns **XML or JSON**.*" As you mention, "*their documentation says that the API supports sending back results in JSON format*". I'm not sure what the confusion is here.

Comment: @esqew - You're absolutely correct!  The docs do say JSON is supported.  I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that Alexa awis only provides XML. I can use

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': key
}
```

and it still returns `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`.

I ended up using `xmltodict` as:

```
import xmltodict
import json
my_dict = xmltodict.parse(response.text)
data = json.dumps(my_dict)
print(data)
```

note `data` is a string and only looks like json. Use `json_data = json.loads(data)` if you need to pass json or access elements with `[][]...`. To extract the alexa ranking:

```
rank=int(json_data['Awis']['Results']['Result']['Alexa']['TrafficData']['Rank'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's in the docs of Alexa:

```
Required HTTP Headers:

Accept: application/xml
x-api-key: "YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Required headers means you HAVE TO use this header and Alexa ONLY provides XML result format. It seems to me that Alexa doesn't provide json format. Header is just for some low-level web request handling procedures rather than application API level.

Comment: i'm not sure :)

Comment: You're right on about why only XML is coming back.  The "Accepts" header is only effective if the server chooses to honor it and is able to return the specified response type. If it can do that is purely a function of the capabilities and design of the particular API.

Comment: "Header is just for some low-level web request handling procedures rather than application API level".  This is not true. This header is for exactly what the OP is trying to use it for.  When supported, it allows the server to send back the result in the client's preferred format.  Where in the server app stack this happens will vary, but it's sometimes done at the API layer.

Comment: @AliceMunin - I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking or saying

Comment: This is absolutely not at all correct. The documentation clearly states: "*A query request is simply an HTTP GET request that returns XML or JSON.*" The *header* itself is required, but nothing about the value that the header is required to be set to. The same documentation page the aforementioned quote appears on includes a sample cURL invocation that's sending the `application/json` value in the `Accept` header!

Answer (score 0):

Since `esqew` pointed out that the API's documentation says that it will return JSON when requested via the `Accepts` header, I decide to try the OPs code myself.  Well guess what...I got back JSON.  I just added `print(response.text)` to the end of the OPs code, and I got this:

```
{
   "Awis":{
      "OperationRequest":{
         "RequestId":"57c6ada1-628d-451b-917f-917c8119406e"
      },
      "Results":{
         "Result":{
            "Alexa":{
               "Request":{
                  "Errors":{
                     "Error":{
                        "ErrorCode":"Forbidden"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "ResponseStatus":{
            "StatusCode":"Forbidden"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Of course, this is an error response because I don't have a valid Api Token, but I'd find it very strange if the API was able to return errors in JSON but not successful queries.  So it seems that something fishy is indeed going on here, as @esqew points out.  I can't think why the OP would be getting a different response format for exactly the same code.  Strange...

PS: I tried requesting XML via the `Accept` header, and that worked as expected as well...I got back XML.